# Python - "The system cannot find the file specified" due to special character in filename

Tags: python, string, unicode, ascii, python-2.x

As part of my python script, I'm testing to see if two files are the same size using:

```
os.path.getsize(dir_file) # dir_file = root path + filename joined
```

But when I encounter a file with some special character in its name (e.g Ü) I get the following error: `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified` with something like `\xf6` replacing the special character.

I've tried encoding `dir_file` to utf-8 like so:

```
unicode(dir_file, 'utf-8') # method 1
dir_file.encode('utf-8') # method 2
```

But that gives me the following error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 79: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Not sure how to get around this problem of character encoding.

Comment: We could guess, but you should specify your version of Python in a tag. Python 2 and Python 3 handle Unicode very differently.

Comment: How did you initilialize and join the contents of variable dir_file exactly?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Oh ok. I'm using Python 2

Comment: @anneb `os.path.join(root, filename)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/11545185 but also consider switching to Python 3: [PEP 519](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/) [helps](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-519-adding-a-file-system-path-protocol) in these cases.

Comment: @ephemient Thanks a bunch. I got it working by decoding the drectory used in `os.walk()` to utf-8 first. This ensured that only unicode paths were returned by `os.walk()`. As sublime text can't print unicode, I just ran the python script in the terminal instead and all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the encoding of the filesystem with `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` to clarify your needs.

Then ensure that the string you pass in parameter uses the same encoding

```
if isinstance(dir_file, str):
 print "ascii"
elif isinstance(dir_file, unicode):
 print "unicode"
```

Give your results, I will update the answer.

Comment: I had it working when I decoded the root directory string to `unicode` before inputting it into `os.walk()`. But when I test the script on a large set of files, about 1 in every 1000 files produces either an `IOError` (when I try to open it) or a `UnicodeEncodeError` (when I try to print the directory). I ran `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` and got 'mbcs' as my result (if that helps)

Comment: The `UnicodeEncodeError` was resolved by encoding the strings to utf-8 prior to printing. The `IOError` still eludes me